# didWriteValueFor not calling for second time when try to write using .writeValue

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an app which we are connecting a chip by BLE and performing an operation like Connect/Read/Edit/Write.

Reading task working properly and try to write data after connection successful with the chip but getting the issue described below:

1. Connect BLE
2. Write first package of `NSData` using the `.writeValue` method on selected peripheral and characteristics.
3. Sent package call `didWriteValueFor` delegate method's as response.
4. Again I sent/write a second package of `NSData` using `.writeValue`
   on different/static/predefined characteristics with it's matched peripheral. But the second time the response is not coming or the `didWriteValueFor` delegate is not calling.

I have managed/converted byte data in data `NSData` same as first to write/sent a package to BLE.

I send package data the first time and it's responding properly, but the second time it's not responding and no delegate is calling `didWriteValueFor` or `didUpdateValueFor`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a different behavior, eliminate the differences. You say you're writing to different characteristics. Write to the same characteristic twice; does it work? Write the characteristics in a different order; does the failure follow the order or the characteristic? Verify that your delegate still exists and is still the peripheral's actual delegate between calls.

Comment: 1) If you have different behavior, eliminate the differences.:-> Actually, As per my functionality, I have to send the 1st package on different characteristics and peripheral and 2nd package on different characteristics and peripheral. So first time sending the 1st package and after it’s a response. I am sending the 2nd package with different characteristics and peripheral. 2)Write to the same characteristic twice:->I have tried the same but same issue. -Question: Do you think, It may issue of package data in 2nd time?

Comment: With a different peripheral? You mean a different CBPeripheral object? Are you sure you've made yourself the delegate for both objects? The goal changing the order is to explore whether the problem is that the second characteristic never works, or if it is an order issue. Even if the protocol does not permit writing to the second characteristic first, you can still try and verify that you receive an error. Simplify your project to the smallest bit of code that creates the problem (I often make a small separate project to experiment).